# Thymeleaf: concatenate expressions

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this expression

```
<h2 class="topmargin_0 bottommargin_30" th:text="${user.name} || ${user.age} || ' years old'"></h2>
```

butn when I run the app. I have this error:

```
Could not parse as expression:
```

Comment: [This](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax) is a great reference page for a summary of much of the core Thymeleaf syntax. String concatenation is included there. I refer to it all the time.

Comment: If you are also using Spring, then [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) is a great reference for SpEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate, use `+`:

```
<h2 th:text="${user.name} + ${user.age} + 'years old'" ...>
```

Or use `|`:

```
<h2 th:text="|${user.name} ${user.age} years old|" ...>
```

UPDATE:
I wrote [a blog post](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/01/11/string-concatenation-with-thymeleaf/) to show all possible string concatentation options in depth.