# How can I append text in href tag of <a> tag

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have an  tag, which should have an href that contains text that needs to be appended.
The below  tag should be "href="open-job?123", here "123" is coming from a different source, the source is a thymeleaf object which is being populated from a model object which is passed from the controller.

**How can I append text in href to contain simple text("open-job") and text from a thymeleaf object("th:text="${Job_Form[0]}")**

```
<a href="open-job" class="btn btn-primary">View Detail</a>
```

I tried the below and as expected, it resulted in error.

```
<a href="open-job+th:text="${Job_Form[0]}">View Detail</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf: concatenate expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502909/thymeleaf-concatenate-expressions)

Comment: `<a th:href="|open-job${Job_Form[0]}|">View Detail</a>`